# Catch WebSocket exception: "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503"

Tags: javascript, web, websocket

I'm trying to implement a WebSocket connection that tries to reconnect itself every X seconds when my site is down, until it's back online again. So far I've got this:

```
var onCloseHandler = function() {
    reconnect();
}

function reconnect() {
    try {
        console.log('Connection lost, trying to reconnect...');
        socket = new WebSocket(myUrl);

        socket.onerror = onErrorHandler;
        socket.onmessage = onMessageHandler;
        socket.onopen = onOpenHandler;
        socket.onclose = onCloseHandler;
    } catch (err) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            reconnect();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

My problem is that, when `onCloseHandler` is called the first time (i.e. when my site is suddenly offline), the `new WebSocket()` call throws the next exception:

`WebSocket connection to '<here_goes_my_url>' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503`

And there's no way to catch it (to call the same function again in X seconds time) or to make the execution move on to the next line. It just crashes, showing the exception through the browser's console, and stops the execution.

Is there any way to catch this exception?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Just to make it clear, the `onclose` event won't get called the second time, I've already checked it. Also, the exception (and thus the impossibility to connect when the site is offline) is fine; what I'm looking for is a way to detect it and drive the execution to the `setTimeout` at the `catch` block.

Comment: is the `onErrorHandler` being called?

Comment: Also, are you sure the `new WebSocket()` is actually throwing an exception (as opposed to logging the error)? Try adding a `console.log` after the constructor to verify that execution is halted.

Comment: @levi No, the `onErrorHandler` isn't being called. Also, if I add a `console.log` right after the constructor it isn't shown (the one right before the constructor is shown).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I ended up using this approach:

```
function reconnect() {
    console.log('Connection lost, trying to reconnect...');
    $.ajax({
        url: dummy_http_url_on_the_same_server
        success: function() {
            //Server is back online
            socket = new WebSocket(myUrl);
            socket.onerror = onErrorHandler;
            socket.onmessage = onMessageHandler;
            socket.onopen = onOpenHandler;
            socket.onclose = onCloseHandler;
        },
        error: function() {
            //Server is still down
            setTimeout(function() {
                reconnect();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

As Ajax calls have an error handler, I used them to check every X seconds (in this example, every 1 second; in my application is a random number to avoid all the clients connecting at the same time) if my server is back online. When it is, then I instantiate the websocket, knowing for sure it won't throw the exception as the server is up again.

Not exactly what I was hoping to find, but at least it works.